# Run script when a command is executed irrespective of the command's arguments

Tags: linux, bash, unix, alias

```
rm -rf
rm -r
rm -f
rm
```

When any of these commands are run I want them to run a certain script.

Something like `alias ?='some_script.sh'`

**(the question mark in this case means the rm command with any arguments.)**

**How can this be done?** I don't HAVE to use aliases, anything that works is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an alias; define a function:

```
rm () {
    some_script.sh
    command rm "$@"
}
```

The standard disclaimer when modifying the behavior of `rm` in any way applies. Don't do this is `some_script.sh` is intended to be a safety net of some kind. You may become reliant on it, and be unpleasantly surprised if you run `rm` on a machine without this safety net installed.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to run the script on every `bash` command, then best way is to append it to a special variable in `bash`, which gets executed every time a command is entered in the prompt.

The [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) variable, all you need to do is append your script `some_script.sh` to it like

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND+="some_script.sh;"
```

Or if you want to script only for the command `rm`, then keeping an alias is the best way to do it. Add the line in your `~.bashrc` and `source` it after making the change.

```
alias rm="some_script.sh; rm"
```